# Is there a word for “I don’t know and I don’t want to guess”?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when you’re answering an online poll that requires certain knowledge to answer correctly. There are several possibilities:

- you know the answer
- you feel confident that you know the answer or are able to guess correctly
- you don’t know the answer and aren’t confident in your guess, so you don’t want to skew the poll results with your low-quality guess

Is there a good verb for the third case. “I’m not sure” is too ambiguous about one’s level of confidence. I’m looking for a a word or phrase that conveys a hesitancy to reply.

Comment: Are you sure you want a verb? Does *uncertain*  or *unsure* explain the hesitancy?

Comment: Why would there be just one word for complex a concept? What single words have you considered and discarded?

Comment: *None of the above*

Comment: Have you considered "I'm sure I don't know?"

Comment: @tchrist It can be a phrase, fine with me. I have considered “I’m not sure” but that’s too ambiguous because it doesn’t tell anything about the person’s confidence in their guess.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest the word **incognizant.**

> : lacking awareness or consciousness -
> incognizant of the danger

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incognizant)

> Not cognizant; without cognizance, knowledge, or apprehension of; unaware, unconscious of.

> 1837   Fraser's Mag. 15 760   Being utterly incognisant of their inquiries, [she] merely shook her head

[Oxford English Dictionary (requires subscription or UK library pass)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93619?redirectedFrom=incognizant#eid)

The [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incognizant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincognizant%3B%2Cc0) indicates that the usage of the word has increased since about the year 2000, returning to levels last seen prior to the 1900s.

> The result is that Americans are cognizant of the imagined threat while Pakistanis are incognizant of the real threat.

[Express Tribune July 01, 2021](https://tribune.com.pk/story/2308147/pakistans-flawed-indian-policy)